# Context not showing variable in Template

Tags: python, django

Hellooo,

I am trying to add a feature to my admin where I can download order details from a PDF file, which has gone successful so far except that only one Model is showing which is Order.Model while there is another one called OrderItems which are the items inside the Model not showing.

I am not sure how to add another context for the OrderItem to appear in the PDF.html

Here is the models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
```

Here is the views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(Order.id)

    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response)
    return response
```

here is the url.py

```
path('admin/order/(<order_id>\d+)/pdf/', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf')
```

Here is the pdf.html template which is only showing as highlighted

```
{% for order_item in order.items.all %}
{{ order_item.item.title }}         <----------Not Showing
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please show where you are rendering the template, since the context is passed when you render the template so maybe you have a problem in that area.

Comment: Would you please explain what do you mean?